# IDA python, list all imported functions

Tags: ida, idapython, winapi

I have the following IDA python script. It sets and removes breakpoints on all calls to library functions:

```
import idc
import idaapi
import idautils

def set_breakpoints():
    ea = idc.ScreenEA()
    for function_ea in idautils.Functions(idc.SegStart(ea), idc.SegEnd(ea)):
        if idc.GetFunctionFlags(function_ea) & FUNC_LIB:
            for ref in idautils.CodeRefsTo(function_ea, 0):
                    idc.AddBpt(ref)

def rem_breakpoints():
    ea = idc.ScreenEA()
    for function_ea in idautils.Functions(idc.SegStart(ea), idc.SegEnd(ea)):
        if idc.GetFunctionFlags(function_ea) & FUNC_LIB:
            for ref in idautils.CodeRefsTo(function_ea, 0):
                    idc.DelBpt(ref)

idaapi.add_hotkey("Alt-Z", set_breakpoints)
idaapi.add_hotkey("Alt-X", rem_breakpoints)
```

Now I want to have the same functionality for imported win api functions (from "Import" tab), but I cannot find any flags that will indicate that function is imported. Maybe someone can point me into right direction to do this. Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

This code snippet was copied from

https://github.com/idapython/src/blob/master/examples/core/list_imports.py

```py
"""
summary: enumerate file imports

description:
  Using the API to enumerate file imports.
"""

import ida_nalt

nimps = ida_nalt.get_import_module_qty()

print("Found %d import(s)..." % nimps)

for i in range(nimps):
    name = ida_nalt.get_import_module_name(i)
    if not name:
        print("Failed to get import module name for #%d" % i)
        name = "<unnamed>"

    print("Walking imports for module %s" % name)
    def imp_cb(ea, name, ordinal):
        if not name:
            print("%08x: ordinal #%d" % (ea, ordinal))
        else:
            print("%08x: %s (ordinal #%d)" % (ea, name, ordinal))
        # True -> Continue enumeration
        # False -> Stop enumeration
        return True
    ida_nalt.enum_import_names(i, imp_cb)

print("All done...")
```

The remaining steps from enumerating imports to setting breakpoints are trivial.

Comment: One note: the entries in the `.idata` section are usually *pointers* to the target functons, not functions themselves, so they'll need to be dereferenced before setting breakpoints.